gopls stops working if build tags are added

No packages found for open file
/home/user/projects/ws-client/request/client_connection_test.go.
This file may be excluded due to its build tags; try adding
"-tags=" to your gopls "buildFlags" configuration See the
documentation for more information on working with build tags:
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/settings.md#buildflags-string.

I use neovim with gopls lsp. The solution for this problem provided by the error above only works for vscode.
I have tried adding tags to other projects of mine, it is not code related, the error persists.
// +build connection

I have this simple tag

Did not find a solution for local projects.
But you can define all build flags in neovim config file:
local lspconfig = require'lspconfig'
lspconfig.gopls.setup{
  settings = {
    gopls =  {
        buildFlags =  {"-tags=integration some-other-tags..."}
    }
  }
}

Not the best solution but at least it works
